# Web service for web

Tags: android, web-services, web, slim

I have that web service

```
$app->get('/students', function(){
require_once('db/config.php');
foreach ($db->students()
             ->order("name")
         as $row){
    $data[]=$row;
}


echo  json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //for android

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('views/students/'); //for web

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array()); //for web

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('singup.php'); //for web

echo $template->render(array('data' => $data)); //for web
});
```

Someone knows how can i call the correct echo for android and for web, because this way the web service do the two echo. I don't want replicate that web service.

Comment: Seems this should be tagged with PHP instead of Android or did I misunderstand?

Comment: work for too, i call that webservice on android app and web app, but because the echos i need to replicate that webservice, one with the frist eco and one without the frist echo and with the twig. I dont know if you understand, bad english

Comment: Check if the request asks for `application/json` or for `text/html` content and render the response respectively.

Comment: i gone see that later, if cant i put there how i call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That work for my problem
http://mobiledetect.net/

Just Download and include on web service file